# How to debug in Nsight in Visual studio when you have multiple gpus

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cuda, gpu, nsight

Does anyone know how to switch between GPUs in Nsight in Visual Studio while debugging, I am programming 2 quadro cards. Code is in cuda C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumrate your cards in your CUDA program, and explicitly choose one of them. Or you can set an enviroment variable before launching your Nsight Monitor, "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0" choose the card with ordinal 0.

You can refer to the deviceQueryDrv sample in CUDA SDK, for listing ordinals of you GPUs. You can also refer for how to enumrate your GPUs.

Comment: i can enumerate my gpus, but is there a way so that I can say in nsight, I want to access the variables of a particular kernel on GPU id '1' and not the primary gpu, whose id is '0'. If I selecting one of the GPUs, then I am setting the number of GPUs to 1 from 2, right?

Comment: Bharat, I may have misunderstood your question. If set the variable I previously replied, only 1 GPU is available.  Is your Cuda program running on two GPUs? You can access menu "Nsight\Windows\Cuda Info 1" when debugging. From there you can see the list of Cuda contexts, and in Block and Warp panel, you will see a context column. You can double click each row to switch focus.